# Create HBITMAP from jpeg memory buffer?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, hbitmap

I want to create HBITMAP from byte array with JPEG format.

I have searched but I only can create it from bitmap file as

```
HBITMAP hbm = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,"fileName",IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
```

Can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: Are you using a library like MFC? If so, there's probably a convenience method that will do this for you easily. Otherwise, you'll have to write some code.

Comment: yes, I'm using MFC libary. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember not all library support loading JPEG but at least GDI+ is doing it

Answer (score 4):

Just use GDIplus.
It supports loading JPEGs, and some other stuff feels much more logically

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Use "Bitmap" class.
When you have the jpeg in a buffer, you need to read it by a stream.

Comment: Image::FromStream().  Same requirements as CImage::Load(IStream)

Answer (score 2):

MFC provides a [`CImage` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5.aspx) that wraps a bitmap object. It provides convenience methods to load and save images in a host of formats, including JPEG, GIF, BMP, and PNG.

So the first order of business is obtaining a `CImage` object representing your `HBITMAP`. You can do this by calling the [`Attach` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b15ctcha.aspx) and passing the handle.

But in this case, it looks like you can skip that entirely and just have the `CImage` object load your image from the file directly. Use the [`Load` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4bytf8.aspx) for that.

Once you've got a `CImage` object representing your image, just call the `Save` method and specify the desired file name with the appropriate extension. According to the documentation:

> If the `guidFileType` parameter is not included, the file name's file extension will be used to determine the image format. If no extension is provided, the image will be saved in BMP format.

**Sample code:**

```
CImage img;
img.Load(TEXT("fileName.bmp"));  // load a bitmap (BMP)
img.Save(TEXT("fileName.jpg"));  // and save as a JPEG (JPG)
```

You can also reverse this pattern, using the `Load` method to load JPEG files and the `Save` method to save BMP files.

Comment: Thanks, but I need create HBITMAP from jpeg buffer (not from file).
I have a jpeg buffer, and I want to create HBITMAP from this buffer.
I don't want to save this buffer into file. Thank you!

Comment: You need to create an IStream so you can use the CImage::Load(IStream) method and load the image from the "buffer".  It isn't exactly clear what that buffer looks like, CImage::Load can only work if it has the proper JPEG file header.  CreateStreamOnHGlobal() is a convenience function, as long as the buffer was actually created with GlobalAlloc().

Answer (score 1):

I found the following code //http://katahiromz.web.fc2.com/win32/loadjpeg.html

The red and blue were swapped, so here is a corrected version with the colours corrected. It uses jpeglib, so you must first compile that. If you need only to convert a buffer, then you can skip the line that loads the file - the details of converting should be the same.

```
extern "C" {         
#include <jpeglib.h> 
#include <jerror.h>
}
#pragma comment(lib, "jpeg.lib")
HBITMAP LoadJpegAsBitmap(const std::string & filename)
{ 

    struct jpeg_decompress_struct decomp{};
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerror{};
    BITMAPINFO bi = {};
    LPBYTE lpBuf, pb = NULL;
    HBITMAP hbm{};
    JSAMPARRAY buffer{};
    INT row = 0;

    decomp.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerror);
    jpeg_create_decompress(&decomp);
    FILE* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
    if (file == nullptr)
    {   
        return NULL;
    }

    jpeg_stdio_src(&decomp, file);

    jpeg_read_header(&decomp, TRUE); // read jpeg file header
    jpeg_start_decompress(&decomp);  // decompress the file

    row = ((decomp.output_width * 3 + 3) & ~3);
    buffer = (*decomp.mem->alloc_sarray)((j_common_ptr)&decomp, JPOOL_IMAGE,
        row, 1);

    ZeroMemory(&bi.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = decomp.output_width;
    bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = decomp.output_height;
    bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = row * decomp.output_height;

    hbm = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&lpBuf, NULL, 0);
    if (hbm == NULL)
    {
        jpeg_destroy_decompress(&decomp);
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    pb = lpBuf + row * decomp.output_height;
    while (decomp.output_scanline < decomp.output_height)
    {
        pb -= row;
        jpeg_read_scanlines(&decomp, buffer, 1);

        if (decomp.out_color_components == 1)
        {
            UINT i;
            LPBYTE p = (LPBYTE)buffer[0];
            for (i = 0; i < decomp.output_width; i++)
            {    
                pb[3 * i + 0] = p[i];
                pb[3 * i + 1] = p[i];
                pb[3 * i + 2] = p[i];  
            }
        }
        else if (decomp.out_color_components == 3)
        {
            // There was talk on Internet about one being RGB and another BGR. 
            // If colors appear swapped, then swap the bytes, and update this comment.
            //CopyMemory(pb, buffer[0], row);

            // Updated color correction
            UINT i;
            LPBYTE p = (LPBYTE)buffer[0];
            for (i = 0; i < row; i += 3)
            {
                pb[i + 0] = p[i + 2]; // Blue   
                pb[i + 1] = p[i + 1]; // Green  
                pb[i +2] = p[i + 0];  // Red    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jpeg_destroy_decompress(&decomp);
            fclose(file);
            DeleteObject(hbm);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    SetDIBits(NULL, hbm, 0, decomp.output_height, lpBuf, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    jpeg_finish_decompress(&decomp);
    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&decomp);

    fclose(file);

    return hbm;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I am looking for. I'm using C with libjpeg, and GDI+ and MFC are out of my consideration. I even thought that I need to create one by painting every pixels with GDI!